# How can I make this function more modular and be used for multiple members of a struct?

Tags: c, function, structure

I am trying to learn C and I am having trouble writing a function for a project I am working on for class.  I need to find the average of 7 different scores that I read in from a file and split into members of a structure.  The problem I am having is I can't seem to figure out a way to write a modular function so I can use the different members of the structure.  I am including the structure as well as the function and prototype I have written.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I have searched and searched and couldn't seem to find anything that would help.

My Structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNAME         50
#define MAXSTUDENTS     100

int count;

typedef struct {

    char  name[MAXNAME];
    float quiz1;
    float quiz2;
    float quiz3;
    float quiz4;
    float midTerm1;
    float midTerm2;
    float final;
    float totalScore;
    char  finalGpa;

}student;
```

My Prototype:

```
float averageQuiz1(int count, student *dataList);
```

My Function:

```
float averageQuiz1(int count, student *dataList)
{
int i;
float total = 0;

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    total += dataList[i].quiz1;

}
return total/count;
}
```

Again, any help in pointing me in the right direction to make this modular so I can replace dataList[i].quiz with another member of the structure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side Note: Calculating the average *in* the loop it useless (except the last calculation). Move that line *below* the closing brace of the for-loop. But at that point `average` is useless, as you're setting it, then immediately returning it, so just accumulate the total and return `total/count`.

Comment: As you can tell, I am new to this and for some reason I'm getting really confused by functions and their prototypes.  Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have much more flexibility if you change your struct so that all the scores are in an array, e.g.

```
typedef enum { // define a new enum to select which score you're working with 
    quiz1,
    quiz2,
    quiz3,
    quiz4,
    midTerm1,
    midTerm2,
    final,
    totalScore,
    NUM_SCORES
} Score;

typedef struct {
    char  name[MAXNAME];
    float scores[NUM_SCORES]; // array of scores
    char  finalGpa;
} student;
```

Then you could have a general purpose `averageQuiz` function where you specify which score you want to calculate the average for:

```
float averageQuiz(int count, student *dataList, Score s)
{
    int i;
    float total = 0;
    float average = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        total += dataList[i].scores[s]; // <<< note that we are summing score `s` here
    }
    average = total/count; // <<< bug fix from @user2722968
    return average;
}
```

and you would then call this as e.g.

```
averageScore = averageQuiz(count, dataList, quiz1);
```

Comment: And this organization makes it easier to calculate the score for each student separately too.

Comment: The line `average = total/count` must be outside the loop

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply.  When you see it written out, it looks so simple.  But I've been pounding my head against the wall to figure this out.  Thank you again, Paul.